# Can I use grep in place of awk?

Tags: android, bash, shell, grep, ksh

I'm attempting to take this output (*linebreak added for readability, please discard on reading*):

```
mCurrentFocus=Window{167ead2f u0
  com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL}
```

and extract this:

```
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
```

using only the tools natively available in Android, such as grep.

The following commands will do it, but they use `cut` `rev` and `awk`.

```
dumpsys window windows | grep mCurrentFocus |
    cut -d'/' -f1 | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
dumpsys window windows | grep mCurrentFocus |
    awk '{print $3}' | awk -F '/' '{print $1}'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know anything about what's available on Android, but this might help you:

```
$ dumpsys window windows | grep mCurrentFocus | grep -o '[^/]*' | grep -o '\S*$'
```

*First grep*: Find the row containing mCurrentFocus

*Second grep*: Print everything up to the first '/'

*Third grep*: Print non-space character suffix